# Google map working fine but,

Tags: google-maps, extjs, touch

I'm having an issue about placing google map in my Sencha touch application .. 
Following is the code..

```
           new Ext.application({
                name:'Touch Start',
            launch:function(){
        var map = new Ext.Panel({
     fulscreen:true,
     items:[
     {
    xtype:'map',
    useCurrentLocation:true,

    }
    ]
    });
this.viewport = map;
 }
 });
```

Well its working fine and gives an alert that "Application Support/iPhone SImulator/5.1/Applictios/887ED997-705D-4F52-AF9C-C740C0979302/maps/app/www/index.html" Would Like to use Your Current Location..

But When I click ok nothing Happen but a blank screen .. 
Please help if anyone has some idea about this.. 
thanx in advance

Comment: `this.viewport = map;` looks odd to me because you already set `fullscreen: true`. Do you see something if you replace your map with a list?

Comment: Well after removing this.viewport = map; i am facing the same problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Addition to [@A1rPun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1449624/a1rpun) answer:

You have an error in your App configuration:

```
name:'Touch Start',
```

is invalid!

Use

```
name:'TouchStart',
```

instead. Whitespace is not allowed. Note that is from that on your Namespace! With the one above your app can't load/resolve any View, Model, Controller or Store.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion phantOm, bur still it is not working . :( I just tried this ...                                         Ext.application({
name:'Maps',
launch:function(){
var map =     Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
layout:'card',
items:[
{ xtype: 'map',
useCurrentLocation: true,
remote:true,
height: 400,
mapOptions: {
zoom: 12,
navigationControl: true,
navigationControlOptions: 
{
style: 'google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT',
}
}
}
]
});  
}
});

Comment: Will you please help me .. I use this for Google API  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
      </script>

Comment: Alert is also shown if i Click on this link .. ..... ..... .... .... ..alert("The Google Maps API server rejected your request. The \x22sensor\x22 parameter specified in the request must be set to either \x22true\x22 or \x22false\x22.")

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [Ext.aplication](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application) that requires a specific folder structure.

To make your example work just write:

```
var map = new Ext.Panel({
    fullscreen:true,
    items:[{
        xtype:'map',
        useCurrentLocation:true
    }]
});
```

PS: fullscreen is with 2 L's

Comment: No, Ext handles the viewport.